# What is the statement i need next to determine my output given a total?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm quite new to JavaScript so apologies in advanced, but I'm wanting too learn!

In my html form I am asking the customer for 3 numbers (number 1,2,3) and then in my JavaScript I am calculating the total of all of them. I need to work out my next bit of code so I can:

1. Given the total of the numbers give I can print out to the customer you're item is free (less than 180) or it has a cost (more than 180)
2. Given the number is under or over a certain amount return an error message

Where would be the best place to go with this ?

```
function Calculate() {
    var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    var number3 = document.getElementById("number3").value;
    // var totalOfNumbers = Number(number1) + Number(number2) + Number(number3);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Number(number1) + Number(number2) + Number(number3);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an **[if construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals)**.

The code would be :-

```
function Calculate() {
    var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    var number3 = document.getElementById("number3").value;

    // use parseInt instead of Number()
    var totalOfNumbers =
        parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2) + parseInt(number3);

    // string message to be displayed
    var message = "";

    // enter you own values
    var minAmount = 0;
    var maxAmount = 1000;

    // checking if total of the numbers is under or over a certain amount;
    // if it is, then showing an error message.
    if (totalOfNumbers < minAmount || totalOfNumbers > maxAmount) {
        message = "Error! Please enter valid amounts."
    } 
    // Checking if total of the numbers is under 180;
    // if it is, then displaying the item is free.
    else if (totalOfNumbers < 180) {
        message = "You're item is free!";
    } 
    // Checking if total of the numbers is greater than or equal to 180;
    // if it is, then displaying the item is not free, and its cost.
    else {
        message = "You're item is not free. It has a cost of $" + totalOfNumbers;
    }

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm getting an odd error however, any number I put in it's giving me the answer if it was over 180, so if the answer is lets say 3 it saves it's over 180. Is it possible the parseInt is adding the fields together? So 3 + 3 + 3 becomes 333?